# Max number of edges in a graph with n vertices without $P_3$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-connectivity, extremal-graph-theory

> Find max number of edges in a graph with n vertices without a $P_3$ structure.
>
> *Note $P_3$ denotes the path with four vertices and three edges.

I have two solutions:

1. dividing n by 5 and forming a star structure for every 5 vertices (center vertex of degree 4 is connected to all 4 other vertices). I believe this is the optimal substructure of 5 vertices as if we add any more edge to this substructure of 5 vertices, it would introduce a path of length 3.
2. dividing n by 3 so we form as many triangles ($K_3$) as possible as 3-cycles do not contain a path of length 3.

The answer should be 2 I believe as 2 is more dense in terms of ratio of edges/vertices but how do i prove that 2. is the optimal way.

Any help is appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why would a star with more than 4 edges be disqualified?

Comment: Hint:  try to prove that every connected component of such a graph must be either a triangle or a star with some number of vertices.

Comment: @RaviFernando thx, i know how to prove that, once i prove that, how do i generalize it to the whole graph?

Comment: @jamesblack The whole graph is the union of its connected components.

Comment: Show that $f(n)\le\max\{n-1,f(n-3)+3\}$ where $f(n)$ is the maximum number of edges in a simple graph of order $3$ containing no path of length $3$.

Comment: $$f(n)=\left\lfloor\frac{4n}3\right\rfloor-\left\lceil\frac n3\right\rceil$$

Comment: By the way $P_n$ usually denotes a path with $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges, so what you are calling $P_3$ would usually be called $P_4$.

Comment: i'm not even sure if the question is restricting a three-edge path as a subgraph or as an induced subgraph